# Crossbrowser way to remove the HTML comment tags from a div content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments

I have this code

```
<div id="_right-content-top">   
  <!-- <iframe src="/ads/banner.jsp" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>  -->    
</div>
```

Using jquery or any other method (pure js) I want to assig the value of this div to another div but without the comment, in this way:

```
<div id="right-content-top">   
  <iframe src="/ads/banner.jsp" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>   
</div>
```

How Can I achieve this task that work in all the browser ? I thank you any help

Comment: ... http://www.whathaveyoutried.com also http://www.google.com :)

Comment: Why do you have it commented in the first place?  If you simply want it to appear, why not use jquery to add that html within the div?

Comment: @alex-kalicki First a loaded this iframe in that div because as you see it is an ad and I want to show it when whole the page is complete loaded, so I check the page when is complete loaded and then I take this content commented and place it in the right div where will be shown (whitout comment)

Comment: From what you're saying I don't see why the iframe needs to be on the page at all to begin with.  It should work perfectly fine to add it via jquery once the page is loaded (I'll provide a more complete solution below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, the best way to load the ad only once the whole page is loaded is to have the following empty div on your page:

```
<div id="right-content-top"></div>​
```

and then run this to add the ad to the div once the DOM has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right-content-top").append('<iframe src="/ads/banner.jsp" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>');
});​
```

or this to add the ad to the div only after the rest of the page fully loads:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#right-content-top").append('<iframe src="/ads/banner.jsp" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function move()
{
    t = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML.slice(5, -4)
    document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = t
}
</script>
<body>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="move()">move</a>
<div id="a"><!-- hello world --></div>
<div id="b"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just because someone wants to do something doesn't mean they should :) We should try and figure out why and direct someone to a less problematic solution than must moving comments around.